# How to track and control issues related to a repo on Github and display them in a personal website?

Tags: git, github, github-api

Can anybody tell how to track and control issues related to a repo on Github and display them in a personal website? How can we display those issues with their labels? How to display issues that have been resolved? 
Can it be done using Github API? How?

Comment: This is pretty broad for Stack Overflow. Please try to focus on a single question at once, and try something first. For example, the GitHub API is very well documented. Have you tried using it yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub API is very well documented.
Start on https://developer.github.com/

See https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/ All answers is there.

Comment: How to fetch number of open issues and number of closed issues for a repository on Github using Github API?

Comment: `GET /issues` And see state.